# is there a default way to make the first letter of the contents appear (eg as a hover) android

Tags: android

I have a listview in alphabetic order and as the user scrolls i want a way to see the 
first letter.Like a phone catalog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can do it using android.widget.AlphabetIndexer. See this link to the [relevant file in Contacts git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java;hb=eclair).

More generally the SectionIndexer interface, which AlphabetIndexer implements, seems to indicate that by implementing SectionIndexer you can enable fast scrolling between sections of a list.

**android.widget.FastScroller** is another key class. It does the actual drawing of the letters, so you probably want to check out that class.

See [core/java/android/widget/FastScroller.java in the platform/frameworks/base.git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/widget/FastScroller.java;hb=HEAD) for the source.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the src from the [git repo](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=summary) and see how they did it!